# placing \lstinline{} in a desription list

Tags: listings, description

I'm using Overleaf. Placing a `\lstinline{mytext}` inside a description list gives a garbled output.
Here is the code:

```
\begin{description}
    \item [\lstinline{one}]
    \item [\lstinline{two}]
    \item [\lstinline{three}] 
\end{description}
```

Can this be done? Is it a problem with `listings`?

Comment: It is not a problem with listings, but that verbatim content is quite fragile, especially in arguments of commands. If you do not need any syntax highlighting you could use `\texttt{}` or the like.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I need to use variable names which have underscores such as download_speed, that is why I am trying to use `\lstinline{}`. Is there another way to get around this, maybe without using `\_`?

Comment: Moreover, using `\texttt{}` removes the bold effect which I quite like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the full force of `\lstinline`, then `\detokenize` might suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\textttx}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[\textttx{xyz_abc}] some description
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a bold typewriter, use package `enumitem` for an easy list definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{DESC}{description}{10}
\setlist[DESC]{font=\ttfamily\bfseries}
\begin{document}

\begin{DESC}
    \item [one] one
    \item [two] two
    \item [three] three
\end{DESC}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you run `pdflatex` then you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beramono}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{DESC}{description}{10}
\setlist[DESC]{font=\ttfamily\bfseries}
 [...]
```

[image]